# 200 balls - picking random from each

Tags: probability

Suppose there are two boxes each containing 200 balls: 100 red balls numbered from 1 to 100, and 100 blue balls numbered from 1 to 100. We pick one ball at random from each box.

(a) Given that at least one of the two balls picked is red, what is the probability that both balls are red?

(b) Given that at least one of the two balls is red and numbered 13, what is the probability that both balls are red?

a. The probability would be 1/2 for the first red ball, and for the second red ball, would it be 99/199?

b. the probability would be 1/200 for the first red ball, and for the second red ball, would it be 99/199?

Not sure how I would finish both of those problems though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) 1/3 (either the first ball is red, the second ball is red, or both balls are red, all with 1/4 probability, but both balls blue is excluded)

(b) hmmm, a bit more tricky. For n = 100, there are 200x200 possibilities, but only 200 + 200 - 1 of them have a red 13. (You have to reduce 1 to not count the case where both balls are red 13.)

Out of 399 possibilities, there are 200 where the second ball is blue, so I'd say 199/399.

Edit: and how coincidental, if you'd take n = 1, the formula (2n-1/4n-1) still holds.

Comment: why is it 199/399 and not 99/199? there's only 200 balls

Comment: There are two boxes with each 200 balls as I understand.

Comment: my bad, completely understand now! thank you very much.